# Перебор списка событий и уведомление о событии Node.js

Tags: node.js

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу на Node.js бота для дс с напоминанием о различных событиях.

Для более ясного понимания вопроса приведу краткий массив :

```js
let List = [
    {id: 0, dayofweek: 1, time: "00:00", nameraidboss: "Name"},
    {id: 1, dayofweek: 1, time: "00:00", nameraidboss: "Name"}
];
```

Первое с чем я столкнулся это то что мне надо уведомлять о полуночных событиях в предыдущий день, к примеру в 00:00 в ПН будет событие а уведомить об этом нужно в 23:00 в ВС ( была идея при добавлении события на ПН 00:00 делать проверку и менять день недели на предыдущий и время на 23:59... Но тут чувствуется костыль ).

И как вообще будет более эффективно делать перебор массива чтобы не использовать циклы?

Comment: У меня 2 вопроса. 1: что такое дс? 2: `List` это определенно json, и мне интересно как так может быть, что ключем выступает массив чисел? Или что это? Первый раз вижу такой синтаксис.

Comment: ДС это Discord, Я привел пример массива чтоб показать что у некоторых событий может быть время 00:00, изменил приведенный код на более корректный для вашего удобства